# I would like to make two different textures one inside one outside

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

I would like to make two different textures one inside one outside
Here is the problem:
I used two textures for the part that is outside, so I can't use the mix shader with geometry otherwise the interior texture only applies to a few places on the wall... How should I do?
[image]

Comment: Please give us a clue.. is this UV? Procedural? There's a tantalizing corner of your node-tree in your picture.. that's what we really need to see.

Comment: Texture PBR of Poly Haven... I don't know if it helps you?

Comment: Thanks.. so they are  an image textures, UV mapped?  Please show us how they are combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second Mix Shader to separate the inside from the outside - just use the *Backfacing* output of a Geometry (Shader) Node as the mix factor. In the image below, I tried to re-create your setup, mixing 2 shaders on the front, and then combining that with a color on the back. You can substitute the green color for anything you like, including the output of yet another Principled BSDF, if you want:

[image: Mix]